# how to extract the pci header type on my machine?

Tags: linux, pci

I am learning out PCI and was eager to know the device types on my machine, I found that `lspci -x` displays the Configuration Space, but I was not able to figure out which one is the header type. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going right `lspci -x` will display the standard hex-dump of the standard part of the config space, out of which we need only the first line (256 bytes) i.e **PCI Device Structure** that I found on https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI

[image]

[image]

to extract this data for individual device you may do this way

```bash
lspci -x | grep "00: \|\." | while read -r line ; do
  if [[ "$line" == *"."* ]]; then
    echo $line
  else
    header_type=`echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f16`
    bin=`echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $header_type" | bc | rev`
    printf "%08d\n" $bin
  fi
done
```

I extracted the 15th byte, converted it into binary and then reversed it.

Hope this helps